# Can I add bundeled main.js file in gitignore for HUGO project?

Tags: javascript, hugo

Can I add bundeled main.js file in .gitignore for HUGO project?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes; long answer: it depends.

If you always build (run the `hugo` build command) when deploying your site, and if that bundled file is generated as a result of that action, then it's safe to ignore it.

Otherwise, if you want your deployment process to be a simple `git clone/pull`, then you need to have all the generated files in version control, i.e. not ignored.